# routerLink problem with AdminLTE integrated on Angular7

Tags: angular

I'm newbie on angular. I have first try on AdminLTE integrated. This is my app.component.html

```
<app-head></app-head>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
<app-setting></app-setting>
```

And also I create another component and called from app-routing as below

```
{
    path: 'opdsystem',
    loadChildren: './main/opdsystem/opdsystem.module#OpdsystemModule'
}
```

This is separated route module.

```
const routes :Routes =  
[  
  {  
    path:'register',
    component: RegisterComponent  
  }  
]
```

Then I use routerLink to call the link but I got a problem on footer display.

```
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a routerLink = "opdsystem/register" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" >Sub menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub menu2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I do not know whether AdminLTE itself problem or I'm do something wrong. So I made youtube video as evidence.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvy3fBhMc2I
```

Thanks for all comments.

Comment: what is your exact problem? you do not explain clear!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an array to routerlink. Use like this: `[routerLink]='["/opdsystem","register"]'`

Answer (score 0):

Update path of loadChildren from the root source

angular.json

`"sourceRoot": "src"`

app-routing file

```
  {
        path: 'opdsystem',
        loadChildren: 'src/**OtherChildFolder**/opdsystem/opdsystem.module#OpdsystemModule'
    }
```

Update routerlink with this: `[routerLink]='["/opdsystem","register"]'`